# Ping returns false even website is online

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, ping

I wrote a simple bash script to monitor my websites.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to check website status (online/offline)

while read site
do
    if ping -w 60 -c1 -q "$site" &>/dev/null; then
        echo "$site is up"
    else
        echo "[$(date +%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S)] $site is not reachable." | slackpost.sh
    fi
done < /home/pi/scripts/www-status/sites.txt # list of sites to check
```

But sometimes I get else block `...$site is not reachable. ...` even when the site is online.

Any ideas what could cause bad pings?

Comment: `ping` requires the remote site to actively respond, something the remote site may decline to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only send a single packet, so you risk quite a lot of false positives.

Packets are routinely dropped during normal, healthy network operation when links saturate. If your single packet drops, you'll think the host is down.

Consider using `wget` instead. It has options like `--tries=10` and `--waitretry=6`, which will give the host a minute to respond with several connection attempts, and several packets per attempt.

This will additionally let you know if the host is responding properly or if it responds with errors.

Comment: Also: ping is sometimes intentionally blocked, wget is not (for websites at least).

Comment: Another potential solution is to use `tcpping` (google it), which uses `tcptraceroute` on the backend. It sends a tcp request on the port of your choice to see if it responds.

Answer (score 4):

I do not understand why you are using `ping` to figure out if the "website is online". `Ping` has no concept of port numbers of the host that the web server is responding on. Ping is ICMP and the web server responds to `HTTP` or `HTTPS`.

If you only want to see if that host is up then ping can be used. Of course, as somebody pointed out "`ping`" and `ICMP` might be blocked on the network / host as well.

To add to it, one of the things that make sense is to evaluate if the web server is returning the proper status code (say 200) for a `GET` request.

Please take a look [`here`](https://serverfault.com/questions/282215/script-to-automatically-test-if-a-web-site-is-available) for details on what needs to be done.

Comment: best answer so far imho.